# p-adic and adelic balls: volume formulae!

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, spheres, adeles

Just like we have formulae for volume of n-balls and $$L^p$$ balls, are there formulae for p-adic and adelic n-balls?

Comment: how do you define (and normalize!) $p$-adic volume? I’ve always normalized $p$-adic volume so that the volume of $\{z:|z|\le1\}$ is $1$. Could you reasonably do otherwise?

Comment: As Lubin suggests, there is a [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) that gives volume to balls in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Comment: If $\mu$ is the Haar measure on $\Bbb Q_p$ such that $\mu(\Bbb Z_p)=1$ then the volume of $\{ (x,y) \in \Bbb Q_p^2,   |x|^s_p + |y|^s_p \leq R^s  \}$ is given by $$(1 - p^{-1})^2 \sum_{n, m \in \Bbb Z, p^{-sn}+p^{-sm} \leq R^s} p^{-n-m}$$

Comment: For instance when =1, =2, we find $1/p^2$ (for every prime ). (Similarly, the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit $L^s$-ball in $Q_p$ should be $p^{-n}$ if $2 \leq n \leq p^s$).